# I have a Map<String, Object> which contains all the headers, but in response I am not able to feed it all

Tags: java, string, object, collections, hashmap

`Map<String, Object> headerMap = JSON_MAPPER.convertValue(reqData.getHeaders(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});`

I have a headerMap which contains headers in a key-value pair.

I need to return these headers in a response builder statement of my controller.
Header accepts (String name, Object value) as parameters

````
      ``` return Response
        .status(reqData.getStatuscode())
        .entity(reqData)
        .header()
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        .build(); ```
````

Please help me out!

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Probably because of this disclaimer while typing a question " Many similarly phrased questions have received feedback like downvotes or requests for improvements.
Consider updating your question title and body to be more descriptive."

Answer (score 0):

You should get a reference to `Response.ResponseBuilder` and then iterate the map of the headers to populate the header values.

Possible solution below (not tested):

```java
public Response foo(RequestData reqData) {
    Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response
        .status(reqData.getStatuscode())
        .entity(reqData)
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

    headerMap.forEach(builder::header);

    return builder.build();
}
```